# Python function help, does someone can tell me why it doesent work?

Tags: python, function

my task is to write a python program removes all characters or strings from a string (text)
specified in a list (strings_list). I got it like this but this doesen't work. Anybody can tell me what i got wrong or did I use a wrong function?
Thanks!!

```
def remove_strings(text, strings_list):
    for strings_list in remove_strings:
        strings_list.remove()
        
        text_cleaned = remove_strings("yes, no, maybe..",
                                      ["yes", ","])
    return text_cleaned
    print(text_cleaned)
```

Comment: what is remove_strings supposed to be in the for loop?

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}` button) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def removechar(text, strings_list):
    newstrings = []
    for i in strings_list:
            
        if text in i:
            newtext = ""
            newtext = i
            newtext = newtext.replace(text, "")
            newstrings.append(newtext)
        else:
            newstrings.append(i)

    print(newstrings)
    return(newstrings)
```

also, `.remove()` isnt a function, you would have to use `.replace(text, "")` instead